# Perl DBI $dbh->column_info for MySQL: DEFAULT value not returned?

Tags: mysql, perl, metadata, default-value, dbi

Referring to [CPAN DBI doc](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.623/DBI.pm#Catalog_Methods), I'm reading about the `column_info` method for a database object, and it doesn't appear to me to return **COLUMN_DEFAULT**.  It's a column in **information_schema.COLUMNS**.  Is this intentional?  Is there a way to get it, other than to query info-schema, that is?

Comment: Do you mean `COLUMN_DEF`? It's listed [here](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.623/DBI.pm#column_info)

Comment: <oh>  Thanks - my eyes are getting crossed reading that document.  Must have thought DEF was short for DEFINITION....  Make it an answer and I'll accept it.